# DNS Propagation: A Record change was successfull but there is a strange behaviour

Tags: domain-name-system

I've changed the A record of my domain name to the IP of my new server.
At the time of doing it, **nslookup mydomain.com** showed the old IP addresses as expected. After a day **nslookup mydomain.com** now shows the new IP address. The services on the server seems to work OK. (I can sync to my owncloud via the desktop app and openvpn works)

The strange thing is, Firefox or Chrome won't open it. I cleared all the caches I can think of, I even created a completely new user on my computer to make sure I reset everything and the page still won't open.

Stranger than that, from the console, with a text based browser, I can do **links mydomain.com** and it works like charm. The website is there, the server is running and clearly mydomain.com points to the correct IP address. Only Firefox and Chrome complains.

What am I missing?

EDIT: I've used Chrome's **chrome://net-internals/#dns** page to see if it points to the correct IP address and yes, it certainly is.

EDIT2: Along with **links**, **Android default browser** also can access the website.

Comment: What *does* happen?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist Firefox does not get e response at all. It stays like no URL was entered at all. Developer tools shows there was a GET request but the response is empty. Chrome says "This site can’t be reached. The web page at https://example.com might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."

Answer (score 1):

The problem was completely unrelated to DNS, turns out. When using SSL with HTTP2, below nginx configuration is needed:

```
ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
```

Why Firefox and Chrome not saying anything about encryption is a mistery though.